# W3 Total Cache minify and gzip issue: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: wordpress, caching, amazon-s3, minify, w3-total-cache

I have a WordPress website that uses W3 Total Cache plugin to configure Minify, Caching and S3 as CDN. I am using Amazon S3 for hosting all the static contents of the website from `wp-contents` and `wp-includes` folders. However, I get the errors like these again and again.

[image: Error Image from Chrome Console]

I have to Log in to the WordPress admin panel and manually purge all the caches to clear these errors but they again come after some time.

Is disabling minification the only solution to this problem? What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, it seems to be related to jQuery being loaded later than execution of this script and it is (I presume) related to the theme you are using.